# Vec3 in OpenGl/Glew/GLSL is not defined

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, freeglut

i am just starting with simple OpenGL/GLSL programming and running into a mistake. I want to build a struct for my data that i use. I would like to save parts of it in vec3 or vec4 etc. But i always get the Error vec3/vec2 not defined.
What am i missing here? Help would be appreciated.
Following a little bit of the example where i get the error.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GL\freeglut.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;
int windowWidth = 1280;
int windowHeight = 800;
int windowStartX = 100;
int windowStartY = 25;

struct HairData {
    vec3 position;
    vec2 uv;
};

void render()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
// Left window
glViewport(0,0,windowWidth/2,windowHeight);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluOrtho2D(0, windowWidth / 2, windowHeight, 0);
glScissor(0, 0, windowWidth / 2, windowHeight);

// Right window
glViewport(windowWidth / 2, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(45.0, (GLfloat)(windowWidth) / (GLfloat)(windowHeight), 0.1f, 500.0);

glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowPosition(windowStartX, windowStartY);
    glutInitWindowSize(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutCreateWindow("Simple Hair Program");
    glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
    glutDisplayFunc(render);
    glutMainLoop();
return 0;
}
```

`

Comment: There are no such "standard" types for OpenGL or the GLEW and GLUT libraries. You need to use another library such as [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.7/index.html) or define these types and their operations yourselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vec3 is only available in GLSL, i.e. in shaders, not in the CPU code.

To replace it, you can define your own datatypes or use a library like [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.7/index.html) that defines similar datatypes.